# How to implement OAuth 2.0 with Open ID Connect on .NET Api project

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am trying to understand how I can implement OAuth 2.0 with Open ID connect on a .NET Web API project

I currently have a WEB API (.net) project that I need to secure and implement Single Sign on.

There is an identity server that provides me all the relevant tokens etc but where I am getting confused is, how my API consumes those.

At the moment I have tried the following strategy but I am unsure if this is best/optimal way!.

I got a login controller that redirects with all relevant params to the identity server (Scope, Client Id etc)

the user gives consent and the identity server redirects back with the code to a "callback" controller, this controller, takes the code , posts it back to the identity server with all the relevant parameters (client secrets so on) and the response contains the access_token and an ID JWT token. All fine so far, however, not sure how to handle authorization locally ?

Currently I use cookie authorization without Identity and just take the claims from the ID Token and pass these to the authentication cookie and created an Authorization policy to only allow access where the required claims are present in the cookie

Is this a clean way of securing an API or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of roles here:

**WEB CLIENT**

This consists of a browser frontend, and a backend for frontend that issues cookies. Such web clients implement OpenID Connect themselves, without an API being involved. The browser calls APIs by routing via its backend, which deals with cookies concerns, then forwards access tokens to APIs.

**WEB API**

This is an OAuth resource server that receives and validates JWT access tokens, then authorizes access using claims. In .NET this would be configured something like this. The API should know nothing about cookies, so that it can also be called by other types of clients, eg mobile apps.

```cs
private void ConfigureOAuth(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = this.configuration.MetadataEndpoint;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = this.configuration.Issuer,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = this.configuration.Audience,
            };
        });
}
```

**SUMMARY**

For the most complete architecture, separate web and API concerns. Then again, you may not have any pressing need to do so in the short term.